# how to filter json data by date range and delivery status

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, object

I have a JSON data from an API in the format:

```js
    const data =  [ 
          { 
          order_id: 1,
           delivery_status: 'pending',
           dispatcher_id: 129,
           shopify_order_reference: '2195824935049',
           updated_at: '2020-04-22T00:09:01.275Z',
           item_count: 1 
           },
         { order_id: 2,
           delivery_status: 'pending',
           dispatcher_id: 129,
           shopify_order_reference: '2216944500873',
           updated_at: '2020-04-22T00:46:27.562Z',
           item_count: 2 
           }]
```

I am trying to filter this son data by date range say min_date = '2020-04-22' and max_date = '2020-04-23' and also by the delivery status say delivery_status = 'pending' or 'completed" as the case may be.
I tried writing this to filter the data depending on the parameter provided the user in the query params (say to make it dynamic). Any help with this?

```
   let query =  { delivery_status: "pending",  min_date: '2020-04-22', max_date: '2020-04-23' }

   const availableFilters = ['delivery_status', 'min_date', 'max_date'];

           const selectedFilterKeys = [];

           const selectedFilterValues = [];

           for (const x in query) {
               if (availableFilters.indexOf(x) >= 0) {
                   selectedFilterKeys.push(x);
                   selectedFilterValues.push(query[x]);
               }
           }
   // filter function
   filterData = (data, query) => {
       const filteredData = data.filter((item) => {
           for (let key in query) {
               if (item[key] === undefined) {
                   return false;
               }

           }
           return true;
       });
       return filteredData;
   };

let result = filterData(data, query);
```

Comment: FYI JSON stands for "Javascript Object Notation." It is a way to transmit javascript objects as text. JSON should never be modified directly. Your question is about  Javascript objects directly, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be like this:

```
filterData = (data, query) => {
    const filteredData = data.filter((item) => {
        for (let key in query) {
        console.log(key)
            if (item[key] === undefined) {
                return false;
            }
             return true;

        }

    });
    return filteredData;
};
```

Your return true command was off. Your code execution was never reaching the else case.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks but remember i also want to filter by the date range. My function is not complete. I want to be able to do something like this
` return date >= startDate && date <= endDate `